# Finding Next LineBreak?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I want to copy an line from the text. The Text looks like this:

```
AD1259WED4
PRINCE CHARLES  //THE NAME
PRINCE CHARLES FATHER // FATHERS NAMES
01/01/1900  //DOB
MALE  //GENDER
```

some times names are shorter like:

```
Joy
Rax
```

here i want to copy name and for that i am using the below code:

```
pos1:= Pos(sLineBreak,s);
ShowMessage(Copy(s,pos1,Pos(sLineBreak,s,pos1)));
```

The code is not at all working as this is mess. Pos1 is returning first linebreak position but how to find the next linebreak ?.

How to copy name correctly?

Comment: Use a string list and assign to the Text property, that will split on line breaks

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thank you very much for the path it is just that simple `sl.strings[1]`. it worked but can you show how can i do with the copy and pos commands just for learning purpose.

Comment: @Arno, take a look at the [`PosEx`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.PosEx) function ;)

Comment: @whosrdaddy i tried with posex giving offset to pos1 but no works.

Comment: Why don't you try some debugging and apply some thought?  To my mind, that's the best way for you to learn.  Try looking at the value returned by `PosEx` to understand where you went wrong.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes sir currently doing that. Good Day !